# How to measure and solve the bottleneck in a website with 60K PV/day

Tags: django, apache, nginx

I'll try to start with the real life example in my case:

I have a website with around 60K page views per day (at peak time, 100 active visitors on site, due to google realtime analytics). **Django+mysql+apache**. 1 Linode server with **1024M RAM** and **4core CPU**, and **amazon S3** service to store static files. It turns out to me now it reaches its bottleneck (peak time it response slow).

One thing I could see is from the memory, nearly 91% of memory being consumed at peak time. But not sure if there are some other bottlenecks.

2 questions:

**1: Where**: If I want to solve this problem, I need to know exactly where the problem sits in. So I'm wondering how could I measure where the bottleneck is?

**2: How**: How could I solve the memory bottleneck? One way I could think of is to simply add more memories, or add more machines using the load balancers (sure it's more expensive...). Another way, not sure, but possibly change from apache to nginx?

**EDIT**:

You could also see the memory usage generated from the `top` command  here, 30 apache instances with each consuming 2 percent (**20M**) of the memory.
http://codepad.org/pUYdZhWq

Comment: Just a remark. Unless my math is wrong, even if those 60K page views were done in 2 hours, that makes it only around 8 page views per second. With a quad-core CPU, this doesn't seem large at all. Are those pages 20MBs large?

Comment: @JBNizet Can't answer your question cause I'm also got confused... From the output of top command, it seems 30 apache instances each with %2 consumption of the memory: http://codepad.org/pUYdZhWq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing a lot more about how your site behaves it's hard to make recommendations. And the list of questions that would need to be answered is huge. Put simply, if you were to pay a competent person to investigate the issue it would cost you an awful lot more than putting another gig of memory in the server.

OTOH, if I were the person being paid to resolve the problem, one of the first things I'd be looking at is the speed of the server - turning requests around faster means fewer requests resident in memory, means less memory used by the webserver (and more for cache/buffers). So start measuring your response times (%D) and analysing the data. Make sure you're using an opcode cache, and enable output compression for your PHP (ob_gzhandler()) and enable compression for CSS javascript and html files on the webserver. Make sure you've stripped all unused modules from Apache and are using a sensible value for the keepalive timeout (2 seconds or less).

If you're running any COMET stuff then, yes you should definitely switch to nginx, otherwise the benefits are limited.

Comment: Just one thing. You mentioned PHP, however OP is asking about Django application.

Comment: I could provide more information, here is the top output: http://codepad.org/pUYdZhWq

Comment: Doh! (thanks Ondrej) Sorry I thought I was filtering PHP stuff in SO. So forget the opcode stuff - make sure it's not using CGI (i.e. mod_python or fastcgi) - the remainder still applies